# Functions: Whats is the difference below using and not using the where clause?

Tags: haskell

I am a newbie with Haskell and implemented a function to calculate BMI (‎Body Mass Index). But I got to make it of two ways:

```
-- Calculate BMI using where clause
:{
calcBmis :: (RealFloat a) => [(a, a)] -> [a]  
calcBmis xs = [bmi w h | (w, h) <- xs]  
    where bmi weight height = weight / height ^ 2
:}
-- Input: calcBmis [(70, 1.7), (90, 1.89)]
-- Output: [24.221453287197235, 25.195263290501387]
```

and

```
-- Calculate BMI using just list comprehension
:{
calcBmis :: (RealFloat a) => [(a, a)] -> [a] 
calcBmis xs = [bmi w h | (w, h) <- xs]
bmi weight height = weight / height ^ 2
:}
-- Input: calcBmis [(70, 1.7), (90, 1.89)]
-- Output: [24.221453287197235, 25.195263290501387]
```

Both work perfectly! The only difference is the use of `where` at the first one. I have seen which `where` is good if I had to declare constants or more than one function. I do not know if exist another way to use it for a while, but until now I learn something like this.

Would I want to know if the difference between both functions is just about clean code, or there is something more special behind it in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two key differences between using a `where` block and making a new top-level declaration.

1. Scoping of the new defined variable. A `where` block has a more limited scope than a top-level declaration: in your example, with the `where` block, I cannot call `bmi` from outside the implementation of `calcBmis`, but with the additional top-level declaration I can.
2. Scoping of the variables usable inside the definition. A definition made in a `where` block can see variable names that are local to the function being defined. In your example, although you didn't use this fact, `bmi` can see the name `xs` in the `where`-block version; the new top-level declaration does not have `xs` in scope. Consequently, when lifting `where`-block definitions to the top-level, it is sometimes necessary to add extra parameters to them, and pass in the local variables as arguments when calling them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now it is clarified for me! It was so good that I do not have more questions. XD

Answer (score 1):

In the first version `bmi` is local to `calcBmis` and could (but doesn't) use the parameter `xs` if it wanted to.

In the second version `bmi` is a global function just like `calcBmis`, so you could call it from anywhere.

So if you enter `bmi 1 2` into GHCi after entering the first code, you'd get an error about `bmi` not being defined, but after the second code, it would work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now it is clarified for me!